# Run oracle sql query in excel?

Tags: excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to have the queries I have written in developer run in excel? I can connect to the db in excel but I'm unsure of how to find and run the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-Data-from-Database-using-Native-Database-Query-Power-Query-f4f448ac-70d5-445b-a6ba-302db47a1b00?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Once you're able to connect, you should be able to query the database in its native language. Select the **Power Query** tab, then the drop-down **From Database -> From Oracle Database**. Simply copy/paste your existing Oracle query into the **SQL Statement** box and you should be good to go.

In case you don't already have it, Power Query is an add-in for Excel. You can find it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379).

Comment: Thanks. When I do that I get a window that says "This connector is not configured correctly. The recommended provider is not installed." Is that ok?

Comment: Sounds like something's not set up right, but upon googling I see that error appears to be from Power BI not from Power Query. Take a look at this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-an-Oracle-database-Power-Query-d7fbd231-a705-4eb7-83b3-a66bfb678395

Comment: What button do I hit to get the area to paste the sql statement?